# Is tzinfo-data needed if the application will run only on Linux docker containers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is tzinfo-data needed if the application will run only on Linux docker containers. Should the following need to be added to the Gemfile

## Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Is tzinfo-data needed if the application will run only on Linux docker containers. Should the following need to be added to the Gemfile

Answer (score 4):

When you create a new rails app, you get this message:
[image]
Basically, you can just remove `gem tzifono-data` from your `Gemfile` if you are running anything except windows, and run `bundle update`.

**The tzinfo-data gem is not needed on Linux.**

Here's a detailed answer https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data/issues/13#issuecomment-287174435

Comment: Its so weird, it didn't work and didn't have time to debug this so had to revert everything while running on an ruby:2.7.1-alpine image